# Confusion about numpy's apply along axis and list comprehensions

Tags: python, object, numpy, vectorization

Alright, so I apologize ahead of time if I'm just asking something silly, but I really thought I understood how `apply_along_axis` worked. I just ran into something that might be an edge case that I just didn't consider, but it's baffling me. In short, this is the code that is confusing me:

```
class Leaf(object):

    def __init__(self, location):
        self.location = location

    def __len__(self):
        return self.location.shape[0]

def bulk_leaves(child_array, axis=0):
    test = np.array([Leaf(location) for location in child_array])  # This is what I want
    check = np.apply_along_axis(Leaf, 0, child_array)  # This returns an array of individual leafs with the same shape as child_array
    return test, check

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test, check = bulk_leaves(np.random.ran(100, 50))
    test == check  # False
```

I always feel silly using a list comprehension with numpy and then casting back to an array, but I'm just nor sure of another way to do this. Am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: `apply_along_axis` never modifies its input.  It returns a new array.

Comment: Mis-worded, I meant that check is the same as child_array in shape

Comment: What is `child_array`?

Comment: An array of `Leaf` instances is going to have dtype `object`. These arrays are no more memory efficient than a regular Python list, and do not perform any computation faster than equivalent code using a regular Python list (and given the cost of array creation, it is often slower). All it provides is ndarray indexing *syntax*. Are you sure you want to be using a NumPy array at all?

Comment: @BrenBarn Just an array of random numbers. An `np.random.rand(x, y)`

Comment: But what is its shape?  Can you give a self-contained example showing what you get and what you want instead?

Comment: @BrenBarn Something arbitrary with two dimensions. For purposes of my application it's (10-1 billion, 10-100). Also, added a small line at the end clarifying, though I don't think it adds a huge amount, since the comments in the `bulk_leaves` encapsulate the issue much better than actually emulating the input.

Comment: @unutbu Well aware, not for the sake of memory efficiency, mostly just to expose a nice interface to other areas of my code. Since I'm mostly using arrays elsewhere it's nice to be able to access things like shape and whatnot without having to think about whether or not something is a list or an np array, and I mostly want to avoid the overhead of casting between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `apply_along_axis` uses `isscalar` to determine whether the returned object is a scalar, but `isscalar` returns `False` for user-defined classes.  The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) for `apply_along_axis` says:

> The shape of outarr is identical to the shape of arr, except along the axis dimension, where the length of outarr is equal to the size of the return value of func1d.

Since your class's `__len__` returns the length of the array it wraps, numpy "expands" the resulting array into the original shape.  If you don't define a `__len__`, you'll get an error, because numpy doesn't think user-defined types are scalars, so it will still try to call `len` on it.

As far as I can see, there is no way to make this work with a user-defined class.  You can return 1 from `__len__`, but then you'll still get an Nx1 2D result, not a 1D array of length N.  I don't see any way to make Numpy see a user-defined instance as a scalar.

There is [a numpy bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2582) about the `apply_along_axis` behavior, but surprisingly I can't find any discussion of the underlying issue that `isscalar` returns False for non-numpy objects.  It may be that numpy just decided to punt and not guess whether user-defined types are vector or scalar.  Still, it might be worth asking about this on the numpy list, as it seems odd to me that things like `isscalar(object())` return False.

However, if as you say you don't care about performance anyway, it doesn't really matter.  Just use your first way with the list comprehension, which already does what you want.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much for finding that! Yup, like I said, it's not a real performance issue, it was just baffling to me. I mean, to be fair, my object isn't a scalar, but I might run some quick benchmarks to see if the len -> 1 hack, or the solution proposed by @hpaulj below have any performance benefit, but knowing why this happens is enough for me. Thanks so much!

Comment: That numpy bug is now patched in master, and should make the 1.13 release

Comment: @Eric: Thanks, that's good news!  What is the numpy position on the underlying issue of `isscalar` always returning false for user-defined classes?

Comment: @BrenBarn: _"Don't use `isscalar`"_ seems to be the solution to that. If you interpret `isscalar` as _"is this of a `numpy.generic` subclass"_, then it works as intended. Almost always, you want `np.ndim(x) == 0`, not `np.isscalar(x)`

Answer (score 4):

The `apply_along_axis` is pure Python that you can look at and decode yourself.  In this case it essentially does:

```
check = np.empty(child_array.shape,dtype=object)
for i in range(child_array.shape[1]):
    check[:,i] = Leaf(child_array[:,i])
```

In other words, it preallocates the container array, and then fills in the values with an iteration.  That certainly is better than appending to the array, but rarely better than appending values to a list (which is what the comprehension is doing).

You could take the above template and adjust it to produce the array that you really want.

```
for i in range(check.shape[0]):
    check[i]=Leaf(child_array[i,:])
```

In quick tests this iteration times the same as the comprehension.  The `apply_along_axis`, besides being wrong, is slower.

Comment: Thanks for going through the source. Don't have a good intuition for whether or not there will be a change in performance, but gotta accept @BrenBard's answer for finding the core issue that was confusing to me.